# Postman Schema Validation of array of JSON

Tags: postman, json-schema-validator

**My Test Data:**

```
 {
     "staffId": 1691580015,
     "staffName": "Test Staff",
     "staffEmail": "teststaff@perpule.com",
     "isAdmin": null,
     "isSuperAdmin": null,
     "shopDetails": [
         {
             "shopId": 5004,
             "shopName": "Spar E2E",
             "shopAddress": "Nagpur",
             "shopLocality": "Nagpur",
             "shopCity": "Nagpur",
             "shopState": "Maharashtra",
             "stateCode": "KT"
             }]

     }
```

**My Test Case code:**

```
var schema = {  
   //"required":["shopDetails"],
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{  
      "shopDetails":{  
         "type":"array",
         "items":[  
            {  
               "type":"object",
               "properties":{  
                  "shopId":{  
                     "type":"integer"
                  },
                  "shopName":{  
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "shopAddress":{  
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}  


//console.log(JSON.stringify(tv4));
pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
  pm.expect(tv4.validate(jsonData, schema)).to.be.true;
});
```

Issue is it failing every time , how to resolve please help ?

Comment: Personally, I think that the `tv4`module is rubbish and causes people more problems than anything else, it hasn't been worked on for years....Are you storing `jsonData` some where as a variable?

Comment: @DannyDainton yes jsonData.  variable... and `tv4` is very usefull , i am having trouble only with  array of *json objects** , all other cases are working good for me